# Call function in another .js file from initialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the initialization function of my google map, I need to call a function from another .js file.

**Problem**: When I tried the following code, I get an error `"Uncaught ReferenceError: getPlacesByBounds is not defined"` when the listener is triggered. How can I solve this problem? I do not want to move that function over to the `initialize()` function as it is too long.

**JS Code**

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var center_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.354183, -71.065063);

    var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        minZoom: 11,
        maxZoom: 19,
        center: center_latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    //instantiate map object
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

    //attach listener to the map object.
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        getPlacesByBounds ();
    });
```

**Additional Info:** The function `getPlacesByBounds()` is within jQuery's `$(function() {...});`

Comment: Is it possible to instantiate the `Map` object at `window.onload`? The other JS file you're referencing in your function call may not have finished loading by the time the function is called. Also, since the `getPlacesByBounds()` function is defined in jQuery, don't you need to prepend `getPlacesByBounds()` with `jQuery.` or `$.` (i.e: `$.getPlacesByBounds();`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the code declaring `getPlacesByBounds` has run before you try to use it. And that `getPlacesByBounds` is visible.

As an aside you should consider creating a namespace for your functions (such as getPlacesByBounds) to avoid polluting the global scope.

Comment: Agreed; create a namespace, set getPlacesByBounds within it. Declaring a utility function within document ready is a recipe for problems like the one you're seeing. It will exist only within the scope of that function, so it's invisible to future requests as well.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the getPlacesByBounds() within jQuery is not loaded at the time the listener is triggered. Are you loading google maps asynchronous? If not try it out: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Async

Comment: Are there any downsides to loading the map with `window.onload`?